# Keycloak: Refresh Token Automatic Reuse Detection

Tags: authentication, keycloak, openid-connect, refresh-token

We are using Keycloak for authentication (OIDC):

- the user input his Username/Password and enter the Frontend Browser page (Client)
- Rest API calls to the Backend (Server) has the Bearer Token (= access token) in the Header
- calls are queued in RabbitMq
- after a long running task the stored Bearer token from the next running task is already expired and has to be renewed by a Refresh Token

**Now the scenario:** someone is able to steal the Refresh Token and get always new valid access tokens. Keycloak should recognize this by "Automatic Reuse Detection" and  requires re-authentication to prevent this!

We tried this out in Postman and were able to use the same Refresh Token on both sides (different Clients in the same Network) several times without any problems.

An other possibility would be to use **Revoke Refresh Token** to ON and **Refresh Token Max Reuse** to 0. But then it is not ensured that the valid user is still able to authenticate because of race condition with malicious users:

1. The Attacker uses the Refresh Token before the valid user
2. the Refresh Token becoming invalid for the valid user due **Revoke Refresh Token**

What are the best practicies here? Any kind of help is very appreciated!

Comment: I think you can mitigate the "(different Clients in the same Network)" issue with verify-token-audience option. The second part, if the attacker is able to get the first refresh token probably the attack can intercept the access token any way, regardless, at this point it looks like your client is pretty compromised anyway

Comment: Your question is currently in the reopen queue, but I'm not familiar enough with Keycloak to decide if it should be reopened, so I'll pass this one. But just to help a bit: is the "revoke refresh token" option 100% related to the "Automatic Reuse Detection" feature? It sounds like these may be two different (although related) questions, which is a close reason on its own. Your original question ("Why was Keycloak not able to recognize this?") sounds like a good question to me, although you might have to describe your test scenario in more detail to make it answerable.

Comment: (continued) It might help to focus on 1 question only to get it reopened. FWIW: [this site](https://auth0.com/blog/refresh-tokens-what-are-they-and-when-to-use-them/#Refresh-Token-Automatic-Reuse-Detection) seems to explain the Automatic Reuse Detection functionality and might explain the things you've observed (which is also why I asked more details about your tests - where both users able to **continue** using the refresh token? That should not be possible I think). I hope this helps (again, I'm not an expert on the topic)